# How are the gradients of a Neural Network calculated just by matrix multiplication?

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, backpropagation

I would have expected some kind of derivative solving equation to be at work in order to back propagate the loss to each neuron. I hope my question is not too confused to answer.
In the network below, why does h_relu.T @ grad_y_pred (y hat - y) produce the gradient for w2? I understand sometimes the derivative is just something you multiply something by. Like the derivative of y = h_relu * w2 being h_relu, which doesn't make much sense to me either. I understand why the derivative of x^2 is 2x and that's about as far as my understanding of derivatives goes.

```
import numpy as np

# N is batch size; D_in is input dimension;
# H is hidden dimension; D_out is output dimension.
N, D_in, H, D_out = 64, 1000, 100, 10

# Create random input and output data
x = np.random.randn(N, D_in)
y = np.random.randn(N, D_out)

# Randomly initialize weights
w1 = np.random.randn(D_in, H)
w2 = np.random.randn(H, D_out)

learning_rate = 1e-6
for t in range(500):
    # Forward pass: compute predicted y
    h = x.dot(w1)
    h_relu = np.maximum(h, 0)
    y_pred = h_relu.dot(w2)

    # Compute and print loss
    loss = np.square(y_pred - y).sum()
    print(t, loss)

    # Backprop to compute gradients of w1 and w2 with respect to loss
    grad_y_pred = 2.0 * (y_pred - y)
    grad_w2 = h_relu.T.dot(grad_y_pred)
    grad_h_relu = grad_y_pred.dot(w2.T)
    grad_h = grad_h_relu.copy()
    grad_h[h < 0] = 0
    grad_w1 = x.T.dot(grad_h)

    # Update weights
    w1 -= learning_rate * grad_w1
    w2 -= learning_rate * grad_w2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Like the derivative of y = h_relu * w2 being h_relu, which doesn't make much sense to me

*These are partial derivative and depends on w.r.t variable. In the end, we have to complete the chain of partial derivative from output to the respective weights.*

Your Network is -

$$x \xrightarrow[\text{}]{\text{}} w_1 \xrightarrow[\text{}]{\text{  h  }} ReLU \xrightarrow[\text{}]{\text{  h_relu  }} w_2 \xrightarrow[\text{}]{\text{ }} y\_pred$$
By definition ReLU is - $f(x)=\max(0, x).$

Derivative of ReLU - $\frac{d}{dx}\text{ReLU}(x)$

=$1 \forall x > 0$

=$0 \forall x < 0$

In backpropagation -

$\frac{\partial y\_pred}{\partial w_2} $ = $h\_relu$  *;since, y_pred =* $h\_relu*w_2$

$\frac{\partial w_2}{\partial h} $ = $1$  *;derivative of ReLU=1,ignoring negative part for simplicity*

$\frac{\partial h}{\partial w_1} $ = $x$ *;since, h =* $x*w_1$

$\frac{\partial y\_pred}{\partial h\_relu} $ = $w_2$ *;since, y_pred =* $h\_relu*w_2$

So, Loss gradient at different weights will be - 

 $L$ at the $y\_pred$

 $L*h\_relu$ at $w_2$ 

 $L*w_2$ at $h\_relu$ 

 $L*h\_relu*1*x$ at $w_1$